# Application to extract & print directory list for Windows

Tags: windows, printing

I'm looking for an application to extract or print the Directory list.

Preferably,

- Can be saved as a text file, PDF file, HTML and XML tables
- Output File Lists Including Metadata
- Filter File And Directory Listings
- Copy, Move Or Delete Files Directly(Optional)
- Set directory recursion depth/levels for sub-directories.
- Show number and sum of the size and length of the displayed objects.
- Output the list as an XML file, including all selected attributes.
- Output the list as a comma- or tab-delimited file or CSV file.

Comment: I recently read an article about an application that may do what you want (I have not tried it yet): https://www.ghacks.net/2019/11/29/dirprintok-is-a-freeware-directory-printing-program-from-the-developer-of-q-dir/

Answer (score 1):

Directory List & Print will do what you have asked:
https://www.infonautics-software.ch/directorylistprint/

It's $22USD.